# How to start working with pug?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I know and use html, js, less. But I'm newbie in nodejs, pug/jade. Just trying to understand how it works.

I've read many tutorials about pug/jade's syntax but I haven't find a tutorial how to work with it.

Where must I write a code?
How to open it in browser?
What I need for that?

Comment: This is a good question, it's just on here (Stackoverflow) people have very high standards for how to ask good technical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on many computers)

Then type out: `sudo npm install pug --global`

This will install pug on your computer. You might not need `sudo` in the command above.

Then type `pug --help`

That will give you this:

```
Usage: pug [options] [dir|file ...]

Options:

-h, --help             output usage information
-V, --version          output the version number
-O, --obj <str|path>   JSON/JavaScript options object or file
-o, --out <dir>        output the rendered HTML or compiled JavaScript to <dir>
-p, --path <path>      filename used to resolve includes
-b, --basedir <path>   path used as root directory to resolve absolute includes
-P, --pretty           compile pretty HTML output
-c, --client           compile function for client-side
-n, --name <str>       the name of the compiled template (requires --client)
-D, --no-debug         compile without debugging (smaller functions)
-w, --watch            watch files for changes and automatically re-render
-E, --extension <ext>  specify the output file extension
-s, --silent           do not output logs
--name-after-file      name the template after the last section of the file path (requires --client and overriden by --name)
--doctype <str>        specify the doctype on the command line (useful if it is not specified by the template)

Examples:

# Render all files in the `templates` directory: $ pug templates

# Create {foo,bar}.html: $ pug {foo,bar}.pug

# Using `pug` over standard input and output streams $ pug < my.pug > my.html $ echo 'h1 Pug!' | pug

# Render all files in `foo` and `bar` directories to `/tmp`: $ pug foo bar --out /tmp

# Specify options through a string: $ pug -O '{"doctype": "html"}' foo.pug
# or, using JavaScript instead of JSON $ pug -O "{doctype: 'html'}" foo.pug

# Specify options through a file: $ echo "exports.doctype = 'html';" > options.js $ pug -O options.js foo.pug
# or, JSON works too $ echo '{"doctype": "html"}' > options.json $ pug -O options.json foo.pug
```

You can follow this pattern with most node.js command line tools.

If you don't have NPM and Node.js installed you'll of course need those too : )

For pug, I'd recommend starting with the examples listed above, and eventually, you'll want to create actual files and directories written in pug, and then use the command line to compile them to HTML.

If you're writing static websites, this will do just fine. If you want to write dynamic websites, where pug creates a different page depending on various user-specific data, you're going to want to learn to use pug with something like express.js.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is many way to work with pug.

Here's how i do :

- First i create a node/express server. he'll handle my route and serve my pug file.
- I then configure my server to works with pug : `app.set('view engine', 'pug');` (this line will tell express that you gonna use pug files).

`app.set('views', './views')` (this line will set the views directory - where you'll create your pug files.

- then you just use `res.render('filename',{variable you want to give to your view});` in your routes.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But I still don't understand.
Sorry for silly questions but can you please tell me about every step in details? How to display result of pug-code in browser?

I install node.js and launch it. Also I launch command prompt.
What should I do next?
Where must I write "app.set('view engine', 'pug');" and other lines?

Answer (score 1):

I've found answer on youtube.

1. First you must launch node.js and node.js command prompt.
2. Type in node.js command prompt:

   npm install pug

   npm install pug-cli -g
3. Create for example "index.pug".
4. Change directory (where you place your index.pug) in command prompt using "cd" function. For example "cd C:\node"
5. Type "pug -w index.pug" in command propmt to get converted index.html.